# Workaround for MYSQL Full GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, database, query-optimization, mysql-5.7

I am working on a query, which requires to be as universal as possible for reuse.
The Query involves GROUP BY.

However I cannot specify the columns as I need it to be  universal.

**Query Purpose:**

- Assigns a time key to each row using the date column.
- Then I am using GROUP BY to get only few values of the group.
- Basically what I want to do is reduce the number of points in a given day.
- So if there are say 4 points in a day, I am using GROUP BY to reduce the same to 2 points in a day and then select the same into say a new db.

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM
   (SELECT h.* FROM testdb h
   WHERE h.date <= '2016-01-02 23:30:00'
   GROUP BY FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(h.date)/((1440/2)*60))
   UNION
   SELECT c.* FROM testdb c
   WHERE c.date> '2016-01-02 23:30:00') m;
```

I can run the above query in MySQL v5.7 and above by disabling ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode.
***When I do that the query result varies.***

> MySQL <5.7  result is **17 rows**.
>
> MySQL >5.7 (with Full Group by disabled) **result 18 rows**.

**My doubts are:**

- Why is the result set varying, the group by shouldn't actually change the result in my case.
- Any work around to achieve the same without having to disable FULL GROUP BY?

I read about MySQL ANY_VALUE, but again it does not work with `SELECT ANY_VALUE(*)`

Need help on how to achieve the above :)
Thank you

**Update 1**

***Local Machine:***

*SQL Version*
5.7.24

*SQL Mode:*

> STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

*Query in question:*

```
   SELECT * FROM
   (SELECT h.* FROM testdb h
   WHERE h.date <= '2016-01-02 23:30:00'
   GROUP BY FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(h.date)/((1440/2)*60))
   UNION
   SELECT c.* FROM testdb c
   WHERE c.date> '2016-01-02 23:30:00') m;
```

***Steps to replicate the problem:***

```
CREATE TABLE testdb ( id int primary key auto_increment,date timestamp);


    INSERT INTO testdb (date) VALUES ('2015-12-31 00:00:00');
    INSERT INTO testdb (date) VALUES ('2015-12-31 06:00:00'); 
    INSERT INTO testdb (date) VALUES ('2015-12-31 18:00:00');
    INSERT INTO testdb (date) VALUES ('2016-01-01 00:00:00');
    INSERT INTO testdb (date) VALUES ('2016-01-01 06:00:00');
    INSERT INTO testdb (date) VALUES ('2016-01-01 18:00:00');
    INSERT INTO testdb (date) VALUES ('2016-01-02 00:00:00'); 
    INSERT INTO testdb (date) VALUES ('2016-01-02 06:00:00'); 
    INSERT INTO testdb (date) VALUES ('2016-01-02 18:00:00'); 
    INSERT INTO testdb (date) VALUES ('2016-12-31 00:00:00'); 
    INSERT INTO testdb (date) VALUES ('2016-12-31 06:00:00'); 
    INSERT INTO testdb (date) VALUES ('2016-12-31 06:01:00'); 
    INSERT INTO testdb (date) VALUES ('2016-12-31 12:00:00'); 
    INSERT INTO testdb (date) VALUES ('2016-12-31 18:00:00'); 
    INSERT INTO testdb (date) VALUES ('2017-01-01 00:00:00'); 
    INSERT INTO testdb (date) VALUES ('2017-01-01 06:00:00');
    INSERT INTO testdb (date) VALUES ('2017-01-01 18:00:00');
    INSERT INTO testdb (date) VALUES ('2017-01-02 00:00:01'); 
    INSERT INTO testdb (date) VALUES ('2017-01-02 06:00:00'); 
    INSERT INTO testdb (date) VALUES ('2017-01-02 18:00:00');
```

*Query result:*

18 rows

**DB Fiddle**

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6082783c8a2c8ab1aa5cb5849bfcb06f

*SQL Version*
5.7.26

*SQL MODE*

> STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

*Query Result:*

17 Rows

Comment: Please include the query in the question as *text*.  Also, explain what the query is supposed to be doing.

Comment: The behaivour of group bx has changed slightly , you can compare bith version to see how https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html  and  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have updated the question with the query its purpose.
The query given below does not work for me as I need to be able to select all the columns in a given table and not just the count. Sorry for the ambiguity :)

I understand this is an edge case, Can it be possible ?? :)

Comment: @AbhilashGopalakrishna So according to your updated question you do not require the count of the records but you want the actual records to be reduced to 2 records per day??

Comment: Is the timezone the same on each computer?

Comment: @RickJames Hi, yup it is, running on the local VM. However, I dont think that would be a problem, as I have run the same query using docker against different versions of MySQL. Also I am just comparing the date format available in the table itself against a given date.

Comment: Hmmm... The Fiddle works for me.  Can you set up another Fiddle that fails in 5.7?

Comment: Simply put this at the beginning of the select:  `SET sql_mode = '';` -- I get 17 rows.  Meanwhile, what do you get with Gordon's suggestion?

Comment: @RickJames https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=7d13988e1b6b0ccd94755b096f280254 this is peculiar, the fiddle is working perfectly. but the same is failing in a docker and my local env.

Maybe it is some other mode that is causing the problem. At a loss :) trying once again in docker and local now with a fresh installation. If that works , will close this question :)

Comment: @RickJames Gordon's suggestion worked for count but without disabling full group by there is no other go, looking to see if there is any way to optimize the query itself rather than set full group by :)

Comment: @AbhilashGopalakrishna - Instead of `sql_mode=''` or `SELECT h.*` or `SELECT ANY_VALUE(h.id), ...`, you could do `SELECT MIN(h.id), ...`.

Comment: @RickJames Hi, I did a fresh install of mysql and tried the same. I am still getting 18 rows contrary to the dbfiddle error, same in docker as well. I will update the question with details of my mysql server. I am puzzled as to why I am getting a row  more in my machine.

Comment: Meanwhile, the outer `SELECT * FROM (...)` can be removed.

Comment: Show us the 17 and the 18 results.

Answer (score 0):

This would seem to do what you want:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(h.date)/((1440/2)*60)) FROM testdb h
      WHERE h.date <= '2016-01-02 23:30:00'
      GROUP BY FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(h.date)/((1440/2)*60))
      UNION
      SELECT c.date
      FROM testdb c
      WHERE c.date> '2016-01-02 23:30:00'
     ) m;
```

Comment: May as well make it `UNION ALL` since the ranges do not overlap.  5.7 (and 10.1) optimizer that to avoid creating a temp table. -- https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=50674

Comment: Hi, I need all the columns, but what is more peculiar to me is the variation in the query result set.
Have updated all the information. where could the problem lie?

Answer (score 0):

Carrying Gordons Answer further:

```
SELECT  ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)/((1440/2)*60)))
                          FROM testdb WHERE date <= '2016-01-02 23:30:00' )
      + ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM testdb WHERE date >  '2016-01-02 23:30:00');
```

That is, don't bother fetching any values, since you seem to only want the count.

(If you do want values, then *which* `id`, etc, do you want??)

This formulation will run faster than any of the others discussed, especially if you have `INDEX(date)`.

Comment: Hi, I need all the columns and not just the count, have updated the question. 
More than this I am not able to understand how the results are varying 1 row.
The SQL modes are also the same, I changed the same and tried the query. But still my machine gives 18 rows.
What could be the problem?

Comment: @I am writing this query such that it works with any table with a `date - timestamp` column, so using `select *`

Comment: @AbhilashGopalakrishna - Then _which_ `id` do you want when several are grouped together??

Comment: I want to get any existing columns.
I am using `select *` with `group by timekey` - new column that I introduce to get required result.

This is ensuring that without knowing what all columns are there in the table, I can apply the group by using the new column - timekey and the select any other column that exist using `select *`